# Sending a string to a listbox (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, listbox

I currently have a string being sent to a TextBox, although instead is it possible to send it to a listbox?

```
private void buttonLB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string machineName = (@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName);
    ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(machineName);
    // Get an array of all the task names
    string[] taskNames = st.GetTaskNames();
    richTextBox6.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, taskNames);
    st.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Winforms or WPF? And think for a second about what you want to do - what would sending a piece of text to a listbox mean?

Comment: @Oded It's the default GUI in MS Visual Studio 2010, I just need to get a string with mutliple values onto a an induvidual row in a listbox

Comment: I don't know what default GUI means. You still need to choose winforms or WPF for a project.

Comment: @Oded - It's a Windows Form Application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the joined task names as a single item

```
listbox1.Items.Add(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, taskNames));
```

Or you can add each of the task names as a separate item

```
foreach (var taskName in taskNames)
{
    listbox1.Items.Add(taskName);
}
```

Comment: @druttka This doesnt seem to work :S, it works fine with a RichTextBox

Comment: You should tell us why it doesn't work? What is it doing? I have tested Items.Add in a new WinForms project and it does work.

Comment: @druttka Oh, have you tested this with my code above? If so could you let me know what you used?

Comment: @Matthew I haven't tested it with your code because I don't have scheduled tasks. I have tested it with a dummy string array: listBox1.Items.Add(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, new[] { "a", "b" })); This works, although the ListBox will not render the NewLine and will show "ab". The second (foreach) option does what you probably intend.

Comment: @Matthew I'll say again that you should tell us *why* it doesn't work. What result are you receiving (does nothing, compile error -- which one, runtime error -- which one)?

Comment: @druttka I get no compile errors, not bad syntax nothing, I click on the button event and nothing happens, no runtime errors etc.

Comment: If "nothing" happens, are you sure the event handler is still attached? Set a breakpoint on the Items.Add line and make sure you hit it. Is it possible that there are no current tasks, and so no items are added, which makes it appear that "nothing" happens?

Comment: @druttka For some unknown reason the button came "unlinked" why I don't know, since the properties were set accordingly, but it was still looking for the old name of the button in the code :/

Comment: @druttka Thanks for your help, genuinely appreciate it :)

Comment: @Mathew Just realized you only have one "t" in your name, sorry for the earlier misspells. Glad you have your listbox issue sorted now.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the textbox's `Text` property, add a `ListItem` to the listbox's Items collection.

```
lstBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, taskNames));
```

Or...

```
foreach(var taskName in taskNames)
    lstBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(taskName));
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'ListItem' could not be found

Comment: @Mathew Sorry about that. I was thinking of the Web version of ListBox. The WinForms version just accepts an object, not a ListItem.

Answer (score 1):

ListBox has [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx) property. You can use [Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx) method to add object to list.

```
listBox.Items.Add("My new list item");
```

Answer (score 0):

For WinForms:

```
listView.Items.Add(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, taskNames));
```

Comment: errr. Did you replace `listView` with the name of your ListView object?

Comment: Yes, it would not of compiled otherwise (in my case)

Comment: did you try adding a constant string to the listView? Does this work? What kind of error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Use AddRange, this can take an array of objects.

Here's some sample code:

Start a new WinForms project, drop a listbox on to a form:

```
 string[] names = new string[3];
 names[0] = "Item 1";
 names[1] = "Item 2";
 names[2] = "Item 3";
 this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(names);
```

For your specific example:

```
// Get an array of all the task names       
string[] taskNames = st.GetTaskNames();      
this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(taskNames);
```

If this is called repeatedly, call clear as needed before adding the items:

```
this.listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score -2):

[A couple seconds worth of googling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288403%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
foreach(String s in taskNames) {
    listBox1.Items.add(s);
}
```

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' could be found

Comment: @Mathew: Have a look at the provided link. Please do at least some of the work yourself

Comment: Your code is significantly different from the code you linked.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. It should be listBox1.Items.add(s);